# Send back to back signed raw transaction

Tags: web3js, transactions, nonce

I have to send multiple signed transactions and from a specific account with nonce via `web3.eth.getTransactionCount`.
Because the call may come parallel, I either get

> replacement transaction underpriced

or

> Transaction was not mined within 50 blocks, please make sure your
>   transaction was properly send.

What is the best way to calculate nonce and make every transaction unique?

I am using web3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and used a global variable to remember the last nonce that was used. If the nonce you get from web3.eth.getTransactionCount is lower than that you can adjust the nonce accordingly. In code, it looks somehow like this:

```
var curnonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account);
while (curnonce <= lastnonce) curnonce++;
lastnonce = curnonce;
```

Works fine and very reliable in my scenario.

Comment: yes, can work for single account, but if we have to use multiple account then we have to maintain a map.

Comment: that's right, since the nonce is account specific.

Comment: somehow, if a transaction is not mined the upcomming transaction fails, not sure ho to resolve it, even not sure why the transaction is not mined

Comment: Which error message do you get when the upcoming transaction fails?

Comment: no error but transaction is not mined, I send 10 transactions in a go with nonce increased 1 by 1

Comment: Sounds like you are doing everything well with regard to the nonce. The issue seems to be somewhere else. Could be a low gas price. If you supply a transaction hash I will check.